# Difference between TCP Listener and Socket

Tags: sockets, tcp, client, serversocket, tcplistener

As far as I know I can create a server using both TCPListener and Socket, so what is the difference between the two of them?

**Socket**

```
private Socket MainSock;
MainSock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
MainSock.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, port));
MainSock.Listen(500);
MainSock.BeginAccept(AcceptConnections, new Wrapper());
```

**TCPListener**

```
    Int32 port = 13000;
    IPAddress localAddr = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");
    TcpListener server = new TcpListener(localAddr, port);
    server.Start();
```

I'm really confused.  The two of them listen for connections, so what is the difference between them?

Updated Code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Net.Security;
using System.Security.Authentication;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.IO;

public class Wrapper
{
    public byte[] buffer;
    public SslStream sslStream;
    public object connector;
}

public class Sock
{
    private Dictionary<string, byte> Connections;
    public event Action<Wrapper> AnnounceNewConnection;
    public event Action<Wrapper> AnnounceDisconnection;
    public event Action<byte[], Wrapper> AnnounceReceive;
    private Socket _sock;

    private X509Certificate certificate = X509Certificate.CreateFromCertFile("exportedcertificate.cer");

    public Sock(int port)
    {
        try
        {
            Connections = new Dictionary<string, byte>();
            _sock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            _sock.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, port));
            _sock.Listen(500);
            _sock.BeginAccept(AcceptConnections, new Wrapper());
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
        }
    }

    private void AcceptConnections(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        Wrapper wr = (Wrapper)result.AsyncState;
        try
        {
            wr.sslStream = new SslStream(new NetworkStream(_sock.EndAccept(result), true));
            wr.sslStream.BeginAuthenticateAsServer(certificate, AcceptAuthenticate, wr);

            _sock.BeginAccept(AcceptConnections, new Wrapper());
        }
        catch (Exception e) { Console.WriteLine(e); }
    }

    private void AcceptAuthenticate(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        Wrapper wr = (Wrapper)result.AsyncState;
        try
        {
            wr.sslStream.EndAuthenticateAsServer(result);
            if (wr.sslStream.IsAuthenticated == true)
            {
                AnnounceNewConnection.Invoke(wr);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) { Console.WriteLine(e); }
    }

    private void ReceiveData(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        Wrapper wr = (Wrapper)result.AsyncState;
        try
        {
            AnnounceReceive.Invoke(wr.buffer, wr);
        }
        catch (Exception e) { Console.WriteLine(e); AnnounceDisconnection.Invoke(wr); }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

They're just different classes that do the same thing, written at different levels. Under the hood the TCPListener undoubtedly calls something very like your first Socket-based code. It;s just there to hide you from some of the gory details.

Answer (score 43):

`TcpListener` is a convenient wrapper for TCP communications.  This allows you to use `TcpClient` for accepted connections--although you can accept sockets instead of clients to use `Socket` instead of `TcpClient`.  You can do the same thing with `Socket`; but you have to deal with some of the TCP-specifics (like `SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp`).  TCP is a stream-based protocol and `TcpClient` recognizes that by letting you do stream communications by providing a stream with `TcpClient.GetStream()`.  `Socket` is at a <strike>higher</strike> different level and needs to support many different protocols like UDP that aren't stream based.

`TcpClient.GetStream` returns a `NetworkStream` object that is suitable for `SslStream`; so, it should be much less work than using `Socket` directly.  The [documentation for SslStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.security.sslstream.aspx) details using `TcpListener` and `TcpClient` for SSL communications.

Comment: in my Asynchronous socket class i used to use socket.BeginReceive to begin receive every message sent from the client. but now after i wrapped my socket class with sslstream to secure the connection idk what is the equivalent of .BeginReceive in ssl

Comment: So please i want you to help me on my updated code above in the main post

Comment: @TorlanOther If you're using `SslStream`, you'd want to use `SslStream.BeginRead`

Comment: every time i try to use this on the above code i get no data idk why could you see my code because i really need your help i am too confused why it did not work

Comment: i don't get the message only i get an empty message, 1000+++ spaces

Comment: so wouldn't that mean that `Socket` is *lower* level than `TcpClient`? This is the only point of your answer that confuses me.

Comment: yeah, poor choice of words I suppose.  I've corrected it.

Answer (score 21):

A [TcpListener](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener.aspx) wraps a socket, and is the server-side analog to the [TcpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient) (which also, of course, wraps a socket).

The TcpListener is preconfigured with TCP (as opposed to the Socket, which can be used with UDP, pure IP, non-IP protocols, etc.) and gives you a TcpClient when handling a connection.

If you're not sure if you need a Socket, and are using TCP - I'd strongly suggest starting with TcpListener/Client as it's a much easier to use interface.

Comment: I want to use SSL Stream but idk how could i use .GetStream with the socket class [First Example]

Comment: @TorlanOther - first, you need a stream on top of the socket: System.Net.NetworkStream will give you that. Then, construct an SslStream on top of the NetworkStream.

Comment: so you mean on the AcceptConnections Callback i make a network stream that gets the stream from the AsyncResult, then i use .GetStream with SSLStream ?

Comment: see my updated code i now can accept connections and authenticate with SSL stream after edited my code as you told me but still can't receive data so please help me

Comment: @TorlanOther - I don't see anywhere you're actually reading from the stream. I presume that's in the unshown event handlers?

Comment: @Timeless - in general, performance of a well-known higher-level abstraction is going to be equivalent or better than naively reimplementing the same abstraction. So the Q is really - do I want (and can afford) this abstraction. The rest is a question best suited for a profiler....

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really answering the question, but you seem to like `TcpClient` better because it has `GetStream()` which you can use with an `SslStream`, but you can get a `NetworkStream` out of a `Socket` by passing the `Socket` as a constructor to `NetworkStream`

i.e. `NetworkStream myStream = new NetworkStream(mySocket);`

Comment: I do not remember writing this.

Answer (score 0):

I know the answer has been given but just to illustrate, when you look at the source code for `TcpListener`, you can see that it's a wrapper for a socket and preconfigured to use Tcp Stream.

[image]