# TcpListener vs Socket

Tags: c#, sockets

Hello i would like to ask what is difference between using this :

```
public TcpListener Listener;
public TcpClient Client;

Listener = new TcpListener(DeafultPort);
Client = default(TcpClient);
Listener.Start();
```

and this :

```
serverSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, 
                                      SocketType.Stream, 
                                      ProtocolType.Tcp);

IPEndPoint ipEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 1000);
```

and also i would like to know if i use first option what is difference between

```
Listener.BeginAcceptSocket()
```

and

```
Listener.Server.BeginAccept()
```

and if i use second option what exactly does these two lines ?

```
serverSocket.Bind(ipEndPoint);
serverSocket.Listen(4);
```

Thanks for answers

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between TCP Listener and Socket](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12361924/difference-between-tcp-listener-and-socket)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The difference between Socket and TcpListener/TcpClient is that TcpListener/TcpClient is easier to use than Socket. Socket can do everything what TcpListener/TcpClient can do. If you new to network programming, TcpListener/TcpClient is recommended. For most task, TcpClient/TcpListener perform similar in performance. Only when you have problems or not enough functionality, should you consider Sockets.

I know that my answer is not technically correct, but in this context, that would suffice.

Answer (score 0):

For any serious solution use Sockets and not TcpClient.  It provides much more control and when using Tasks or threads and asynchronous methods with byte buffers usually a necessity.

Comment: This might be better suited as a comment as it doesn't really provide a difference between the two classes.